# React native table component cannot show right column

Tags: javascript, react-native

all. I am learning the examples about how to create a table by using a react-native-table-component. I want my table scrollable and the first column is the pressable button. but it cannot show the button in the first column and only one column left. I don't know what is the problem, can you guys help me out.

here is my table class

```js
class MyOrdersTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ["Img", "Qty", "C.ICode", "Name", "Price", "Amount"],
      widthArr: [40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140],
      tableData: [
        ["1", "2", "3", "4", "2", "3"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "c"],
        ["1", "2", "3", "4", "b", "c"],
        ["a", "b", "c", "d", "2", "3"],
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    const element = (img, index) => {
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._alertIndex(index)}>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>button</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>;
    };

    return (
      <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <View>
          <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#C1C0B9" }}>
            <Row
              data={state.tableHead}
              widthArr={state.widthArr}
              style={styles.header}
              textStyle={styles.text}
            />
          </Table>
          <ScrollView style={styles.dataWrapper}>
            <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#C1C0B9" }}>
              {state.tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
                <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
                  {rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                    <Cell
                      key={cellIndex}
                      data={
                        cellIndex === 0 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData
                      }
                      textStyle={styles.text}
                    />
                  ))}
                </TableWrapper>
              ))}
            </Table>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: { height: 50, backgroundColor: "#537791" },
  text: { textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "100" },
  dataWrapper: { marginTop: -1 },
});
```

But all the table data comes into one column, like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7oXz.jpg)

Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

It because your styles are error, you missed some style setting like `styles.row`

You could change your styles like this(from [example](https://github.com/Gil2015/react-native-table-component#example4) and yours code):

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: { height: 50, backgroundColor: "#537791" },
  text: { textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "100" },
  dataWrapper: { marginTop: -1 },
  row: { flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#FFF1C1' },  /// the main cause
  btn: { width: 58, height: 18, backgroundColor: '#78B7BB',  borderRadius: 2 },
  btnText: { textAlign: 'center', color: '#fff' },
});
```

But you have to Fine-tuning that you change the index for button and it's style.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did check the example, and modified my own code, it worked! those examples are very great!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers, and by [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the most helpful answer to any
question you ask. :)